# find the length of array using map function ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to find the length of an array using ES6 using the below code but it does not work.

```
a=[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
result = a.map(d=>({d[0]:d.length}))
console.log(result)
```

This works:-

```
a=[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
result = a.map(d=>({name:d[0], length:d.length}))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `{d[0]:d.length}` is invalid syntax.

Comment: are you asking why the first doesn't work but the second one does?

Comment: @nick thats correct.

Comment: Because the first is invalid syntax, and your engine should tell you that with an error message. I'll search a dupe target on how to use computed property names...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ES6, to create a key for an object from a variable, you have to wrap with `[]`.

For example:

```js
const a = 'first name';
const name = {
  [a]: 'john',
};

console.log(name);
```

So this is what you are looking for:

```js
a=[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
result = a.map(d=>({[d[0]]:d.length}))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this if you're trying to end up with an array of objects with the first element of the original array as the property name and the length of the array as the property value:

```
a=[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
result = a.map(d=>({[d[0]]:d.length}))
console.log(result)
```